# SQL - How to find all email addresses?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, database-administration

I'm looking to find a specific email address that could be emailed via an alert or notification on a SQL instance.

Is there a way to query and find all email addresses that could receive a Sql Job alert or notification?  An employee that used to need the alerts no longer needs to be receiving the emails and there are a lot of servers and databases to look through.

Is it possible to query this information?

I've tried looking into the following tables, but they are not giving me the info I'm after.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysnotifications 
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysjobactivity  
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysjobhistory 
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysoperators
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The following let me know what email addresses are in notifications

```
USE msdb;
GO

SELECT      j.name AS JobName
          , j.job_id
          , j.originating_server_id
          , j.name
          , j.enabled
          , j.description
          , o.name
          , o.enabled
          , o.email_address
FROM        dbo.sysjobs      j
LEFT JOIN   dbo.sysoperators o ON (j.notify_email_operator_id = o.id)
ORDER BY    JobName;
```

Adapted from: https://basitaalishan.com/2012/08/12/how-to-find-sql-agent-jobs-without-notification-operator-configured/